# error occured installing mongo db

Tags: mongodb

D:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.4.9\bin>m
ongod.exe   --dbpath=D:\mongodb --logpath=D:\mongodb\log.txt --install
Mon Feb 24 13:08:02.680 Trying to install Windows service 'MongoDB'
Mon Feb 24 13:08:02.681 Error connecting to the Service Control Manager: Access
is denied. (5)

Comment: not a programming question, and not enough informations to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The access denied does indicate that you lack the permissions to install a windows service. Try to run as administrator (right mouse-> run as administrator).
If you are running from a shell, start an admin shell by clicking right on the shell in the startmenu and then start as administrator